# Parameters added to build in the fly not passed to downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, triggers, parameter-passing

I have Job_1, and Job_2.
***In Job_1,***

**Step 1: Execute system Groovy script**

```
import hudson.model.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def param = []
param.add(new StringParameterValue('ARTS', "safsaf"))
def pa = new ParametersAction (param)
build.addAction(pa)
```

**Step 2: Trigger/call builds on other projects**

```
Projects to build: JOB_2
Add parameters: Current build parameters
```

**Step 3:**

```
Execute Windows batch command
echo arts  = %ARTS%
```

***In Job_2,***

**Step 1:**

```
Execute Windows batch command
echo arts from Job_1 = %ARTS%
```

Build Job_1, it does print out:

> arts  = safsaf

build_2 was successfully triggered, and print out:

> arts from Job_1 = (blank)

it appears that only parameters in Job_1 defined in the **This build is parameterized** section can be passed to the downstream projects.

*is this the expected behavior? How can parameters added in the fly be passed along?*

Answer (score 1):

I tried and this works:

in Job_1, 
define a **string parameter "ARTS"** in the **This build is parameterized** section, 
and change Groovy script from

```
import hudson.model.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def param = []
param.add(new StringParameterValue('ARTS', "safsaf"))
def pa = new ParametersAction (param)
build.addAction(pa)
```

to

```
import hudson.model.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
build.replaceAction(
  new ParametersAction(
    new StringParameterValue('ARTS', 'safsaf')))
```

to overwrite the value of **"ARTS"**, instead of adding a new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](http://Parameterized%20Trigger%20Plugin) a try. My downstream job was kicked off by a post build step `Trigger parameterized build on other projects` with `Current build parameter` from the plugin instead of the regular downstream job. Anything defined in `This build is parameterized` in Job_2 would pick up parameters passed from Job_1.

I may not be using this absolutely correct and I think there is a limitation on what can be captured vs cannot, but so far this captures all desired parameter from Job_1 for me.

Comment: thanks, but that is not my issue. I am using the plugin and the trigger you mentioned. also, I want the parameters added in JOB_1 with groovy script to be passed to JOB_2.

Comment: You redefined the same parameter in Job_2?

Comment: Yes, if you are passing `arts` from job 1, you will need to define `arts` in `This build is parameterized` in job 2.

Comment: No. if ARTS is defined as parameter in the This build is parameterized section of Job_1, it goes automatically to Job_2, you do not need to redefine it; again, if ARTS is added in the fly with groovy script, it does not go to Job_2.